# Thymeleaf + Spring: How can I offer null (meanig: "nothing is selected") as the default select option in a non-required field?

Tags: spring, select, enums, null, thymeleaf

I need a select-one-option field (e.g. as a drop-down) where it is not required for the user to select an option.

I have an enum:

```
public enum Activity {
SINGING,
SPORTS,
TV,
SLEEPING;
}
```

Now, in the GUI I want a drop-down list with following display values: [**"-"**, "Sing", "Sports", "Watch TV", "Sleep"].
So I put in my `messages.properties` file:

```
favoriteActivity.SINGING = Sing
favoriteActivity.SPORTS = Sports
favoriteActivity.TV = Watch TV
favoriteActivity.SLEEPING = Sleep
```

The default selection should be "-", as this is not a required field. In the database this would be saved as `null`. A typical example to be found in the WWW is like this:

```
<select th:field="*{favoriteActivity}">
     <option th:each="activity : ${T(com.facebook.Activity).values()}"
             th:value="${activity}"
             th:text="#{${'favoriteActivity.' + activity}}"></option>
</select>
```

But that solution is missing the "-" (nothing selected) option.

How to do this?

## **Solution:** --- Works!!! ---

```
<select th:field="*{favoriteActivity}">
     <option th:value="null">-</option>
     <option th:each="activity : ${T(com.facebook.Activity).values()}"
             th:value="${activity}"
             th:text="#{${'favoriteActivity.' + activity}}"></option>
</select>
```

I added one `<option>` with `th:value="null"` and the display value "-".
This worked!!! Very easy solution - just no documentation of it anywhere.